# tab keypress/TextInputAction.next navigates to next input form

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a pretty standard login form. On Web it's pretty standard to have tab navigation ---press the tab key on the email textfield to navigate to the password textfield (and vice versa). On mobile, the TextInputAction.next should work the same way. But how do i do that in flutter?

Here's my simple login form:

```dart
class LoginFormState extends State<LoginForm> {
  // Create a global key that uniquely identifies the Form widget
  // and allows validation of the form.
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Build a Form widget using the _formKey created above.
    return Scaffold(
        body: Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'Enter your email'),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                autovalidate: true,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 28,
                ),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                obscureText: true,
                autocorrect: false,
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Enter your API key'),
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 28,
                ),
              ),

            ],
          )),
    ));
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a [FocusNode](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FocusNode-class.html) for each `TextFormField`, then you need to assign it to each `TextFormField`, and then in the parameter `onEditingComplete` you need to call `requestFocus` of the `FocusNode` of the next `TextFormField`.

Checkout this official [tutorial](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/focus) for more information .

And checkout [flutter_form_bloc](https://github.com/GiancarloCode/form_bloc/tree/master/packages/flutter_form_bloc) that have a simplifies API for do this.

```dart
class LoginForm extends StatefulWidget {
  LoginForm({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  _LoginFormState createState() => _LoginFormState();
}

class _LoginFormState extends State<LoginForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  FocusNode _apiKeyFocusNode;
  FocusNode _otherFieldFocusNode;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _apiKeyFocusNode = FocusNode();
    _otherFieldFocusNode = FocusNode();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the focus node when the Form is disposed.
    _apiKeyFocusNode.dispose();
    _otherFieldFocusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Enter your email'),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                autovalidate: true,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 28,
                ),
                onEditingComplete: () => _apiKeyFocusNode.requestFocus(),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                focusNode: _apiKeyFocusNode,
                obscureText: true,
                autocorrect: false,
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Enter your API key'),
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 28,
                ),
                onEditingComplete: () => _otherFieldFocusNode.requestFocus(),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                focusNode: _otherFieldFocusNode,
                obscureText: true,
                autocorrect: false,
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Other field'),
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 28,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )),
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: For me, the tab key doesn't trigger `onEditingComplete`. The enter key does.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me to have tab properly take me to the next field:

```
onChanged: (text) {
  if (text.contains('\t')) {
    text = text.replaceAll('\t', '');
    _nextFocusNode.requestFocus();
  }
},
```

Comment: please note that `text = text.replaceAll('\t', '');` has no effect on the textfield's text